# Why pandas read_json storting columns alphabetically?

Tags: python, json

```
import pandas as pd
qwer = pd.read_json("https://bitbay.net/API/Public/BTCPLN/trades.json?sort=desc")
qwer
```

why read_json is changing columns order and how i can fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do:

```
qwer = qwer[["date", "price", "type","amount", "tid"]]
```